# Polo 1.2s 100,000 service

Tags: servicing

Just got a polo 1.2s and it is on 99,000 miles.
Not much service history.
What is involved in a 100,000 mile service.
Going to do oil, coolant & filters.

Comment: What year is the Polo? I would recommend you get hold of a workshop manual ('Haynes' or similar), which will have all the information you need for that exact model

Comment: Link to the VW America service schedules is here; http://forums.tdiclub.com/showthread.php?t=372242 However, I wouldn't wait until 100,000 miles to perform a full service on a car on 99,000 miles with an unknown history.  I'd just do a full service ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

If you don´t have a service history you should expect to have to do a full service.

You didn´t state your exact model. I suppose you have a timing chain - if not the most important thing would be to check the belt and change it if any doubt.

If it has a chain, VW had some problems with those - see if your´s runs ok.

Then the usual things like:

- Oil
- Oil filter
- Air filter
- Passenger air filter
- Spark plugs
- Aircon service

Depending on wear:

- Belt(s)
- Belt Tensioner(s)
- Water pump
- Fuel filter
- Shocks
- Brakes!
- Brake fluid

Comment: I agree with this. If you don't have a service history to go off of, then there's really no set list for this "interval". The list is literally anything that needs to be replaced, given that it's aged and/or has been neglected. While "If it's not broke, don't fix it" might seem to apply, if you have the funds, you're always going to be better off with quality new parts than aged old parts, relative to basic maintenance items.